# how to use biml offline schema

Tags: schema, offline, biml

I have defined a table in BIML that does not exists. 
I then create the table using ExecuteSQL, and want to load that table.
However BIML will fail as it tries to query the non existent table. 
I have already provided the column mapping so it doesnt need to query the table anymore.
This thread [Create table before the dataflow in BIML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450082/create-table-before-the-dataflow-in-biml/53670587#53670587) mentions the offline schema, but there is not much content on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Metadata>
        <OfflineSchema Name="OfflineSchema1">
            <Items>
                <Item Name="[Schema].[Table]" ConnectionName="ConnName">
                    <ExternalTableSource Table="[Schema].[Table]" />
                </Item>
        </OfflineSchema>
    </Metadata>
</Biml>
```